# Excel VBA function to remove letters at end of string

Tags: vba, excel

VBA experts,

I'm looking to build a function which will remove last letters [A-Z] from a string variable.

For example:

```
Sub Example()
Dim MyString() as string
...
ReDim Preserve MyString(3)

MyString(1) = "ABC345A"
MyString(2) = "DEFG6789BC"
MyString(3) = "AHIL2431LTR"

MyString(1) = RemLetters(MyString(1))
MyString(2) = RemLetters(MyString(2))
MyString(3) = RemLetters(MyString(3))
...
...
End Sub

Function RemLetters(MyString)
???
End Function
```

...

I'm expecting function to return:

```
MyString(1) = "ABC345"
MyString(2) = "DEFG6789"
MyString(3) = "AHIL2431"
```

So all the letters up to first number should be removed...

Cheers,
Andy

Comment: and have you tired anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Testet this solution and it works. It looks always at the last Char and looks if it is a number or Not. If not it cut off the last Char and so on.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MyString() As String

ReDim Preserve MyString(3)

MyString(1) = "ABC345A"
MyString(2) = "DEFG6789BC"
MyString(3) = "AHIL2431LTR"

MyString(1) = RemLetters(MyString(1))
MyString(2) = RemLetters(MyString(2))
MyString(3) = RemLetters(MyString(3))

End Sub

Function RemLetters(MyString As String) As String
Dim bolExit As Boolean
bolExit = True
Do While bolExit = True
    Select Case Asc(Right$(MyString, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                'IsLetter = True
                MyString = Left$(MyString, Len(MyString) - 1)
            Case Else
                'IsLetter = False

                bolExit = False
        End Select
Loop
RemLetters = MyString
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your prompt reply. Looks like this example is what I need exactly. **However** other solutions are good as well and I see already other functions were I can use them. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution might be what you are looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Function RemLetters(MyString As String) As String

Dim i As Long

MyString = StrReverse(MyString)
For i = 1 To Len(MyString)
    If Asc(Mid(MyString, i, 1)) >= 48 And _
        Asc(Mid(MyString, i, 1)) <= 57 Then Exit For
Next i
RemLetters = Mid(StrReverse(MyString), 1, Len(MyString) - i + 1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

The pattern `(\w+\d+)(\w+)` says to match 2 groups. First group is some letters, followed by some numbers. Second group is some letters. Then the `Replace` function says to replace the original string with just the first group, ignoring the second. This leaves you with just the first group of some letters, and some numbers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()

    Dim MyString() As String

    ReDim Preserve MyString(3)

    MyString(1) = "ABC345A"
    MyString(2) = "DEFG6789BC"
    MyString(3) = "AHIL2431LTR"

    MyString(1) = RemLetters(MyString(1))
    MyString(2) = RemLetters(MyString(2))
    MyString(3) = RemLetters(MyString(3))

    Debug.Print MyString(1)
    Debug.Print MyString(2)
    Debug.Print MyString(3)

End Sub

Function RemLetters(MyString) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim strOut As String

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "(\w+\d+)(\w+)"
        .Global = True
        strOut = .Replace(MyString, "$1")
    End With

    RemLetters = strOut

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
Public Function RemoveCharFromString(ByVal stringValue As String) As String

    Dim idx As Long, charCounter As Long
    For idx = Len(stringValue) To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(stringValue, idx, 1)) Then Exit For
        charCounter = charCounter + 1
    Next idx

    RemoveCharFromString = Left(stringValue, Len(stringValue) - charCounter)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Or RegEx can be used like this also...

```
Function RemLetters(MyString) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim strOut As String

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "\w+\d+"
        .Global = False
        If .test(MyString) Then strOut = .Execute(MyString)(0)
    End With

    RemLetters = strOut

End Function

Sub Example()

    Dim MyString() As String

    ReDim Preserve MyString(3)

    MyString(1) = "ABC345A"
    MyString(2) = "DEFG6789BC"
    MyString(3) = "AHIL2431LTR"

    MyString(1) = RemLetters(MyString(1))
    MyString(2) = RemLetters(MyString(2))
    MyString(3) = RemLetters(MyString(3))

    Debug.Print MyString(1)
    Debug.Print MyString(2)
    Debug.Print MyString(3)

End Sub
```