# Remove or add text after a specific character in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have lot of data in my excel sheet , i want to remove all text after Last  (-) character . 
Here is sample data like in my sheet

```
"This-is-car-44"
"This-is-my-school-ok"
```

I want look like this

```
 "This-is-car"
 "This-is-my-school"
```

i want to remove all text after lats - , so is their any formula to do this. 
and one thing more if possible can i do like this in excel

```
 "This-is-car-44"
    "This-is-my-school-ok"
```

to look like this

```
  "This-is-car/"
    "This-is-my-school/"
```

i mean after last - remove all text and add this / in end .
thanks.

Comment: Hi what have you tried so far? Maybe this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818241/excel-vba-function-to-remove-letters-at-end-of-string/43818460#43818460

Comment: @Moosli hi , thanks for reply , i tried text to column tool , search and replace tool , formula find stings " but not got result what i want . try google and other forums lot of search but nothing help me , im new to excel so in last i post it here may be got help . thanks but i dont understand answer given on above link . thanks

Comment: Ok. what do you not understand? And what did you try so far? You could use aswell the Split() Method

Comment: Also, [here's a non VBA answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/350264/6609896) to get the last word in the string, you could easily then use `LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-LEN(*last word in A1*))` to achieve the desired results (where `A1` contains your data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are OK with excel formulas, please try this,

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))),"/")`

[image]

Comment: @hardy Thats Great!! Please upvote if you found this useful.

Comment: yes i tried but my points not enough for upvote . when i will reach on that rank will vote for sure .

Comment: @hardy Thank you !!

Comment: i dont know why someone give negative vote ( down vote ) to my question . so this downgrade my points , when anyone voteup my question i got points and if then im able to vote i will do for sure . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Sub RemoveLastStingPart()
Dim rng As Range
Dim intLastRow As Long
Dim strTemp As String
Dim aryTemp() As String




With ActiveSheet

    intLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rng = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(intLastRow, 1))

    For Each cell In rng
        strTemp = cell.Value
        aryTemp = Split(strTemp, "-")
        strTemp = ""
        For i = 0 To UBound(aryTemp) - 1
            strTemp = strTemp & aryTemp(i) & "-"
        Next i
        strTemp = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = strTemp
    Next cell


End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks dear , one last question before run on lot of data i want to know that this can remove all text after last - or add / in last . anyways thanks again thanks for help

Comment: it will remove at every string the text after the last "-". If you want to add "/" you can add it at the Point when im Writing the value back to the Cell